# Howto get and post data via jQuery from JIRA REST API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jira, jira-rest-api

We are using JIRA 6.4.5 in our company but I am struggeling fetching data from its API REST interface. I have been trying now for the last couple of days, getting stuck on a cross-domain problem or that I don't know the user credentials so I cannot do any server-side either.

Ideally I am having a jQuery page where the user will use his own credentials/session for querying the JIRA data. The JIRA REST API is located at **srv1.mydomain.xyz** and I am using **srv2.mydomain.xyz** as my webserver with my code.

I have read the [JIRA REST API Reference](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/).

I have tried various Javascript/jQuery stuff - in the below example I am trying to submit 1h 30minutes to a specific issue:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://srv1.mydomain.xyz/rest/api/latest/issue/proj-3/worklog",
    dataType: "json",
    method: "post",
    data: { time: "1h 30m",
            comment: "Test" }
}).done(function(data) {
    alert("Success");
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    alert("Failed");
});
```

I get this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://srv1.mydomain.xyz/rest/api/latest/issue/proj-3/worklog?time=1h+30m&comment=Test.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'https://srv2.mydomain.xyz' is therefore not
>   allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

I then looked more in to this and saw that Atlassian has something called **Atlassian Connect** so I tried with this:

```
AJS.$.ajax({
    url: "https://srv1.mydomain.xyz/rest/api/latest/issue/proj-3/worklog",
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
    async: false,
    method: "post",
    data: { time: "1h 30m",
            comment: "Test" }
}).done(function(data) {
    alert("Success");
}).fail(function() {
    alert("Failed");
});
```

But I get a similar error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://srv1.mydomain.xyz/rest/api/latest/issue/proj-3/worklog.
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'https://srv2.mydomain.xyz' is therefore not
>   allowed access.

I have also looked in to if I could do this server-side from my PHP enabled server in the same domain as the JIRA server but as I don't get the base64 encoded credentials when doing a `phpinfo()` then I don't think I can use this approach either (and I don't want to prompt the user for credentials).

I am painfully aware that my problem is related to cross-domain protection but I cannot find any examples on how to fix it? It would be great if the JIRA server could set a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` for certain hosts but I assume this is not a configuration option (I am not in control of the JIRA server).

Comment: Did you see this answer: https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/69356/cross-origin-resource-sharing-with-jira-rest-api-and-javascript

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely a cross-domain case. And believe me, it exists for your own protection  ; )

The method I use is to send the jQuery request to a server-based processing page, which then authenticates and interracts with the Jira server. In your case, since srv1 and srv2 are under the same domain, srv2 (webserver) can talk to srv1 (Jira) using internal IPs (https://10.50.25.87:8080/rest/api/latest/issue/proj-3/worklog, for example) so the cross-domain issue doesn't apply.